# WPF and XML getting the next node element and display in textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

I have a problem with WPF and XML.
What I am trying to do is display an xml element in a TextBox  which I can do fine with this code

```
xElem.Load("/XMLFile.xml");
XmlNodeList name = xElem.GetElementsByTagName("Name");
txtBox.Text = name[0].InnerText;
```

The problem that I am having is that when the user clicks on a button the txtBox.Text should be equal to the next node “Name” element value (so onLoad txtBox.text would be equal to "Cut" and when the user clicks on a button it should equal to "Paste"). Im not sure how I should go about doing this.

My XML looks like this

```
<GESTURESET>
  <GESTURE>
    <Name>Cut</Name>
    <Description>Cut The Object</Description>
    <Number>1</Number>
  </GESTURE>
  <GESTURE>
    <Name>Paste</Name>
    <Description>Paste The Object</Description>
    <Number>2</Number>
 </GESTURE>
 <GESTURE>
   <Name>Zoom In</Name>
   <Description>Zoom In on The Object</Description>
   <Number>3</Number>
 </GESTURE>
</GESTURESET>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `private int iterator = 0;`

Then

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (iterator < name.Count)
        {
            txtBox.Text = name[iterator].InnerText;
        }
        iterator++;
    }
```

Comment: That makes sense, I feel like a complete idiot now lol! dont know why I didnt think of that solution. Probably because I was thinking about the problem for too long. Well thanks for the reply and help :)